# How to detect key pressed in Javascript inside textarea input?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, textarea, text-editor

I am trying to create a simple Javascript text editor that only makes paragraph breaks to entered paragraphs inside textarea input. while saving textarea input value in database they strip out the paragraph breaks and I also don't want to use all other present text editors because I only need the paragraph breaking (br tag) to be placed while hit <kbd>enter</kbd> key and should be saved like that with the tag inside the database. I could not find the solution by Googling.

Comment: Are you in control of the backend?

Comment: yes, actually i want the text editor to be in the backend.

Comment: I mean, do you have access to the code that saves the data in the database?

Comment: Yes. its my own page. I am developing it. I want my backend to be friendly to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<textarea id="txtArea" onkeypress="onKeyDown();"></textarea>

<script>
    function onKeyDown() {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;

    // If the user has pressed enter
    if (key == 13) {
       alert('enter');
    return false;
    }
    else {
    return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may consider using something to replace newlines with `<br>` tags on the server side rather than trying to insert the tags in the textarea itself. PHP has the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function for example.